# How to get Detailed Explain Plan?

Tags: database, oracle, performance, sql-execution-plan

I worked on management studio in the past and remember explain/query plan was descriptive like it used to tell

1) Order in which statements will be fired

2) Number of rows return by each statement

**I am using "explain plan" by OracleSQL developer  but i don't see above features. Is there any other good free tool ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Order in which statements will be fired

[Adrian Billington](http://www.oracle-developer.net/index.php) has created an "[XPlan Utility](http://www.oracle-developer.net/utilities.php)", to extend the output of DBMS_XPLAN to include the execution order of the steps. The following output shows the difference between the default output and that produced by Adrian's XPlan Utility.

For example,

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT *
FROM   emp e, dept d
WHERE  e.deptno = d.deptno
AND    e.ename  = 'SMITH';

SET LINESIZE 130

-- Default Output
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3625962092

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |     1 |    58 |     3   (0)| 00:00:53 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |         |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |         |     1 |    58 |     3   (0)| 00:00:53 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EMP     |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_DEPT |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPT    |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:18 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("E"."ENAME"='SMITH')
   4 - access("E"."DEPTNO"="D"."DEPTNO")

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Let's see the extended plan to see the order of steps. See the **ORD** column:

```
-- XPlan Utility output
@xplan.display.sql

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3625962092

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Pid | Ord | Operation                    | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |     |   6 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |     1 |    58 |     3   (0)| 00:00:53 |
|   1 |   0 |   5 |  NESTED LOOPS                |             |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   1 |   3 |   NESTED LOOPS               |             |     1 |    58 |     3   (0)| 00:00:53 |
|*  3 |   2 |   1 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | EMP         |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:35 |
|*  4 |   2 |   2 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK_DEPT     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   1 |   4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DEPT        |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:18 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter("E"."ENAME"='SMITH')
   4 - access("E"."DEPTNO"="D"."DEPTNO")

About
------
  - XPlan v1.2 by Adrian Billington (http://www.oracle-developer.net)


18 rows selected.

SQL>
```

> Number of rows return by each statement

In **SQL Developer**, the **explain plan window** has the **cardinality column** which shows the **number of rows**.

In **SQL*Plus**, using **DBMS_XPLAN**, you can display in a readable format. The **rows column** shows the **number of rows**.

See [How to create and display explain plan in SQL*Plus](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/). Few good examples and usage [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_xplan.php).

Comment: Thanks Lalit. i downloaded that utility but not sure how to get the plan for last executed statement. What i tried is :- Explain plan for  Select * from .... and then run xplan.display.sql with parameters ("PLAN_TABLE", NULL, "TYPICAL")

Comment: To get the Plan for last explained SQL statement, just execute in SQL*Plus as : `@xplan.display.sql`

Comment: when i run `@xplan.display.sql` from sqlplus it says Error: cannot fetch last explain plan from PLAN_TABLE

Comment: @emilly Are you sure? Because it works for me. Could you just execute the SQL(no explain plan for) and then run `@xplan.display.sql`. If you still face issue, then check the `statement_id` of the previous SQL and pass it as an argument to the script. Should work. If you open the script, on the top there are examples given for different ways of usage.

Comment: @emilly DId the script work with SQL Developer too? I mean, did you run as an external script? Anyway, I am glad that you got it working.

Comment: Yes it worked. I just pasted the content under blank worksheet and ran it as script.